# How to update stored passwords from SHA1 to password_hash

Tags: php, mysql

I am kind of new to PHP and MySQL. I have a list of 200 passwords stored in MySQL using `SHA1`. I would to update these to `password_hash()`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you updating an existing system from using passwords hashed with sha1 and want to store them using password_hash(default) ?  The whole point of the hash is that it is one way.  You could save the password in the new hash form after a successful login.  Since you would have the cleartext password at that time.

Comment: What do you mean by "update them to `password_hash`"? `password_hash` can be used to hash using different algorithms.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is getting down-voted, this is a real issue that comes up when migrating from poorly built user management systems.

Comment: Probably cause the question is not clear enough. You cannot technically "update" a password to `password_hash`. It does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this directly as the SHA1 hash is not reversible. You can only calculate the password_hash when the user logs in succesfully.

Comment: ....which therefore means that you need some mechanism of identifying the hash used and applying the correct transformatiopn when the user *attempts* to log in (yes, I know that's obvious, but then so is the fact that hashing should be irreversible)

Comment: Using password hash there is a prefix of "$2y$"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot generate the new hash without having the plaintext.

What I would do in this situation would be to force all of the users to reset their passwords after the new hashing algo is in place. If you already have a password reset system this should be fairly easy. If not you'll have to build one.

This is how I see it working

- You discard all of the sha1 passwords as soon as the new system is ready. Immediately.
- When a user tries to login, if they do not have a password hashed with the new algo, send them a password reset email.
- The reset email will contain a link with a unique ID that will allow the user to create a new password

You could slowly migrate to the new system by updating user's password to the new hash as they login, but you would still be storing the weaker hash until a user logs in. I think it is better to just discard the old system and start fresh rather than trying to juggle the old and new hashes.

Answer (score 1):

The hash mechanism used by password_hash is one-way which means that there is no way to get the actual value from the hash. I will make two assumptions here:

1. You want to convert from `SHA-1` to `password_hash` default.
2. You have users logging in regularly.

Create an extra column in your password table for storing the new hash. When a user logs in successfully, hash the password using the default hash and store it in the new column. After a certain period of time, you will have most of the hashes converted. Flag the remaining users and ask them to reset their passwords. Obviously, your password checking mechanism will have to be modified to check the password using the default value first. If the value of the hash is empty, then you will have to proceed with the SHA-1 hash (and its "conversion").

In a real world scenario, this will be a better solution for your customers than asking all the customers to reset their passwords.

Comment: "Better" is subjective in this case. Having poorly stored passwords is a real security concern. You could argue that hanging on to those sha1 hashes any longer than absolutely necessary is irresponsible.

Comment: Complete resetting would still need the users to log in once using the SHA-1 hash. My solution demands the same. I have improved my solution a bit to bring more clarity.

Comment: Password resets do not require the user to know the old password. That would defeat the purpose. I'm referring to the "forgot your password" style reset. Using that type of reset would allow you to discard the old passwords immediately.

Comment: @mtinsley is absolutely correct, tourniquet_grab's answer is a good answer but when users log in a new password should be requested from them and then **the new password is stored in the 'new password' column of the DB**. The current password should not be saved in both columns, as if the database details have already been compromised then it doesn't matter how they're stored, the compromised details will still be effective.

Comment: And if you think your details haven't been -or won't be- compromised, why change your hashing algorithm at all..... QED

Comment: Okay. I did not realise that you were referring to a forgot password style reset. I agree that my solution poses a security risk. It will depend on how likely an attack is on the system concerned in that time frame. Actually, one of my friends faced this problem and this was the solution implemented by them. For him, it would have caused a lot of frustration to those users who failed to check their e-mails (since they would try to log in with the correct password and fail). The risk was insignificant in that scenario.

Comment: @Martin I was surprised why nobody had used that as an argument till now. By the way, your previous comment contradicts what mtinsley said in his comment because you are still suggesting that the user should log in once. If the password has indeed been compromised, then it does not matter whether you ask for a new password or not.

Comment: No, when the user now logs in they should be ***forced*** to set a new password, which is then saved with the new hash, rather than updating any *current* data with a new hash. IF data such as password keys have been compromised then adding a new hash is irrelevant if the plaintext password is known to an outsider. I was meaning that mtinsleys answer was an improvement on your answer because a new hash should always require a new user password, to prevent cross-hash breaches and maintain security. My second comment was just to underline that the reason for a new hash should be the same.

Comment: @Martin Well, how does the user log in?

Comment: The user logs in with their usual details against the usual hash., once this log in is confirmed they are then presented with a change of password form to write a new password, which is then saved ***to the new hash column*** in the database and the old hash column is emptied or otherwise updated to show this change has occurred, such as 'pwd = 'updated'` to tell the login script to log in using the other - `password_hash()` hash field in the DB. Does this make sense, or do you have a confusion? :-)

Comment: Your PHP should then check `if (pwd == 'updated'){` to then use the new password column with the new password hashing functions. If the above IF statement is untrue then route the user through the password update form I described above. The user has to log in to update their details because only the user knows their password, that's the point of hash algorithms. Cheers

Comment: In my solution, the user's password will be saved using the new hash. Once the new hash has been saved, the old hash will not be used. So, as far as I can see, asking the user to create a new password after logging in won't make a difference. I don't think this was mtinsley's solution anyway since he clearly said "Password resets do not require the user to know the old password."

Comment: Hi @tourniquet_grab, my methodology is that a user logs in with their old password and then are asked to provide a new password which is saved with the new hashing algorithm.  This works equally as well if the user receives a "forgotten password" email to their provided address (although I think this is less secure), it still has a security layer extra against if the users password is already known to an outsider, then changing the hash does nothing to prevent false entry.

Comment: @Martin So is your methodology my solution + asking the user to change the password once he logs in?

Comment: @Martin I do not understand why you think mtinsley's method is less secure. I think it is very secure since even if the attacker knows the password, he would not be able to log in. A successful login would only trigger an email which would go to the actual user's email address. That's why I upvoted his answer. I did not include such steps in my solution since the OP asked a way to update the existing passwords.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. I think mtinsley's additions to your answer improve its absolute security by changing password when changing hash algorithm to minimise risk. There is nothing wrong with your answer, but I have tried to elaborate on an improved way of doing it. Please don't think i'm saying your answer is wrong, it's not, but I suggest and recommend improvement. I think mtinsley is correct to request  new passwords when setting a new hash, but that his improvement on your answer can be further inproved by setting a new password once logged in rather than by email link. :-)